# Linux open source tool for Request tracking, Inventory control and MRBS

Tags: linux

I have installed the `Request tracker tool` in my RHEL machine.

I have also a meeting room booking system ([MRBS](http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/)) in my RHEL machine. Also, I can see there are some open source `Inventory of items tools` available.

I wanted to know if there is any open source tool which has all these 3 features combined together so that I can use a single login to all these tools.

Comment: can you give some more details about the tools. Are they browser based? Which request tracker tool and which inventory tool besides `mrbs`

Comment: I see there is an add-on feature to Request tracker for inventory control. They are browser based only. Here is the link of the asset management tool am talking about. http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/AssetTracker. However, I do not see any add-on feature like MRBS that comes with Request tracker.